# Materials that effectively block IR partially

Tags: infrared-radiation

I would like to know what are the effective materials that can partially block IR (but not fully) of wavelength 8-14 um. My idea is to blur the images taken from a thermal camera by adding this piece of material in front of the camera lens. IR cut filters will block all the IR. I tried different kinds of plastic from cling wrap to ordinary plastic bags. Seems cling wrap cannot block IR at all while plastic bags block too much of it. I believe the solution may also depend on the thickness of the material (or the number of layers), and I would welcome any suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Do you need a notch filter for wavelengths 8-12µm? Or do you just want to block anything >8µm? There are filters in this wavelength range (night vision): http://www.buhlergroup.com/northamerica/en/process-technologies__high-vacuum-thin-film-coating__precision-optics.htm#.Vl8J2nuNefQ

Comment: @Timeless I think both will work for me, since the thermal camera I am using (FLIR Lepton) only detects IR of wavelength 8-14um, so anything outside the range should not be detected in the image anyway, I suppose blocking them won't affect the image.

Comment: I would try to contact one of these companies offering filters in this region. They have perhaps some cheap filters on stock. I don't understand the purpose of a filter, do you think radiation outside the sensitive region has some influence on your pictures?

Comment: @Timeless Maybe I am referring to the term "filter" in a broad sense, actually anything that just partially block LWIR 8-14um would be fine for the purpose of my question.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to blur the image use an IR transparent material and roughen the surface to diffuse the light.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to block just that wavelength while letting all others through? If so wouldn't you need a completely transparent material like glass? I believe there is a type of glass that does block most IR, and I think that most of the work done on the subject involves glass.